# 1 post per category on homepage and counting those posts

Tags: theme-development, homepage, categories, frontpage

What I'm trying to do on my homepage is to pull the latest post from each of 6 categories but then I need the variable $counter to increase (+1) for each post so that I can style them properly.

I've managed to display the latest post from each category in the right order, but by doing that I can't get $counter to work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="col1">

        <?php 
             if (get_option('woo_show_carousel') == 'true' AND !is_paged()) { include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/includes/featured.php");}
        ?>

        <?php 
        if (is_paged()) $is_paged = true;

        if (get_option('woo_slider_exclude') == "true") $shownslides = get_option('woo_shown_slides');
        if(empty($showslides) || get_option('woo_show_carousel') == 'false'){
            $showslides = array();
        }  

         $showvideo = get_option('woo_show_video');
         $vidtags = get_option('woo_video_tags');
         if(!empty($vidtags)) {
            $vidtags_array = explode(',',$vidtags);
         } else {
             $vidtags_array = array();
         }

         global $wpdb;
         foreach ($vidtags_array as $tag_name){
             $tag_name = trim($tag_name);
             $tagid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_ID FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name='$tag_name'");
             $tagids[] = $tagid;  
         }                
         $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

            $taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
    $param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
    $term_args=array(
         'include' => '3,4,5,6,11,14',
         'orderby' => 'ID',
         'order' => 'ASC'
        );
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
    if ($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $args = array(
                    "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
                'post__not_in' => $shownslides,
                'tag__not_in' => $tagids,
                'paged'=> $paged
                );
         query_posts($args);


         $home_content = get_option('woo_home_content');
         $home_boxes = get_option('woo_home_boxes');

         if (have_posts()) : 

         $full = FALSE;

         $width = get_option('woo_full_thumb_width');
         $height = get_option('woo_full_thumb_height');

         if( $home_boxes == 'On') { $small = TRUE; }
         elseif ($home_boxes == 'Off') { $full = TRUE; } 
         else {  $large_posts = intval($home_boxes); }

         $counter = 0; 
         while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            $counter++;
            $post_class = 'full'; 
            if( ($counter > $large_posts OR $small == TRUE) AND $full ==  FALSE)
            {
                $width = get_option('woo_boxed_thumb_width');
                $height = get_option('woo_boxed_thumb_height');
                if( $small == FALSE ) $counter = 1;
                $small = true;
                    if ($counter%2 == 0 ) { $post_class = 'fr';  } 
                    else { $post_class = 'fl'; }
            }

         ?> 
        <div class="post-outer post <?php echo $post_class; ?>">

            <div class="post-inner post-alt">       

                <?php woo_get_image('image',$width,$height); ?> 

                <h2><a title="<?php _e('Permalink to ',woothemes); ?><?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="category-head cufon"><?php the_category(', ') ?></p>


                <?php if ($home_content == 'false') { ?>
                    <p><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt(), '<a><strong>'); ?></p>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php the_content(__('Continue Reading',woothemes)); ?>                     
                <?php } ?>            

                </div><!--/post-inner-->
            </div><!--/post-->

            <?php if ($counter%2 == 0 AND $small == TRUE ) { echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>'; } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; 
        }
        }
        wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>

        <div class="more_entries">
            <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(); else { ?>
                <div class="fl"><?php previous_posts_link(__('&laquo; Newer Entries ',woothemes)) ?></div>
                <div class="fr"><?php next_posts_link(__(' Older Entries &raquo;',woothemes)) ?></div>
                <br class="fix" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>      

        <div class="fix"></div>


        <?php 
            if (get_option('woo_show_video') == 'true') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/includes/video.php");}
        ?>

        <?php 
            if (get_option('woo_show_talking_points') == 'true') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/includes/talking-points.php");}
        ?>

    </div><!--/col1-->
```

Comment: You have a lot of stuff going on there.  I think you need to put your `$counter = 0;` above `if (have_posts()) : `

Comment: Chris, I deleted my last comment and fixed the code below because I had made a mistake that I hadn't noticed.

Moving the '$counter = 0;' didn't have any effect on its own, but changing it to 'static $counter = 0;' and moving fixed it completely.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well after a good bit of searching I seem to have this working, I hope this helps someone.

```
    <div class="col1">

        <?php 
             if (get_option('woo_show_carousel') == 'true' AND !is_paged()) { include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/includes/featured.php");}
        ?>

        <?php 
        if (is_paged()) $is_paged = true;

        if (get_option('woo_slider_exclude') == "true") $shownslides = get_option('woo_shown_slides');
        if(empty($showslides) || get_option('woo_show_carousel') == 'false'){
            $showslides = array();
        }  

         $showvideo = get_option('woo_show_video');
         $vidtags = get_option('woo_video_tags');
         if(!empty($vidtags)) {
            $vidtags_array = explode(',',$vidtags);
         } else {
             $vidtags_array = array();
         }

         global $wpdb;
         foreach ($vidtags_array as $tag_name){
             $tag_name = trim($tag_name);
             $tagid = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_ID FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name='$tag_name'");
             $tagids[] = $tagid;  
         }                
         $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

            $taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
    $param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
    $term_args=array(
         'include' => '3,4,5,6,11,14',
         'orderby' => 'ID',
         'order' => 'ASC'
        );
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
    if ($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $args = array(
                    "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
                'post__not_in' => $shownslides,
                'tag__not_in' => $tagids,
                'paged'=> $paged
                );
         query_posts($args);


         $home_content = get_option('woo_home_content');
         $home_boxes = get_option('woo_home_boxes');

         static $counter = 0; 

         if (have_posts()) : 

         $full = FALSE;

         $width = get_option('woo_full_thumb_width');
         $height = get_option('woo_full_thumb_height');

         if( $home_boxes == 'On') { $small = TRUE; }
         elseif ($home_boxes == 'Off') { $full = TRUE; } 
         else {  $large_posts = intval($home_boxes); }

         while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $counter++;
            $post_class = 'full'; 
            if( ($counter > $large_posts OR $small == TRUE) AND $full ==  FALSE)
            {
                $width = get_option('woo_boxed_thumb_width');
                $height = get_option('woo_boxed_thumb_height');
                if( $small == FALSE ) $counter = 1;
                $small = true;
                    if ($counter%2 == 0 ) { $post_class = 'fr';  } 
                    else { $post_class = 'fl'; }
            }

         ?> 
        <div class="post-outer post <?php echo $post_class; ?>">

            <div class="post-inner post-alt">       

                <?php woo_get_image('image',$width,$height); ?> 

                <h2><a title="<?php _e('Permalink to ',woothemes); ?><?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="category-head cufon"><?php the_category(', ') ?></p>


                <?php if ($home_content == 'false') { ?>
                    <p><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt(), '<a><strong>'); ?></p>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php the_content(__('Continue Reading',woothemes)); ?>                     
                <?php } ?>            

                </div><!--/post-inner-->
            </div><!--/post-->

            <?php if ($counter%2 == 0 AND $small == TRUE ) { echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>'; } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; 
        }
        }
        wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>

        <div class="more_entries">
            <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) wp_pagenavi(); else { ?>
                <div class="fl"><?php previous_posts_link(__('&laquo; Newer Entries ',woothemes)) ?></div>
                <div class="fr"><?php next_posts_link(__(' Older Entries &raquo;',woothemes)) ?></div>
                <br class="fix" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>      

        <div class="fix"></div>


        <?php 
            if (get_option('woo_show_video') == 'true') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/includes/video.php");}
        ?>

        <?php 
            if (get_option('woo_show_talking_points') == 'true') { include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/includes/talking-points.php");}
        ?>

    </div><!--/col1-->
```